# Multiple monitor configuration lost in plasma desktop after reboot

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xrandr, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I am using the Fedora 30 Beta KDE spin with plasma 5.15.4 and trying to set-up a persistent configuration of my 3 desktop monitors with the built-in `systemsettings5`.

However, once in a while after I update, this configuration is lost. Is there a kind of script that I could use to run at boot and enable the configuration automatically without drag-and-drop-ing?